# How do backbone and head architecture work in Mask R-CNN?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, image-processing

[image: Architecure of Mask R-CNN]

In this diagram, we see the two convs. It is said that these convs are a part of the **Fully Convolution Network** (FCN). In their paper Mask R-CNN (He et al., 2018), they mentioned something about the **backbone** (ResNets/Feature Pyramid Network ) and the **head architecture** of the model. I am just wondering how are they related to FCN and the two convs in the diagram. This diagram is also the first figure in their paper, just in case you can't see it.

Comment: Please link the paper to your post for ease.

Comment: Here's the paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.06870.pdf

Answer (score 17):

The backbone refers to the network which takes as input the image and extracts the feature map upon which the rest of the network is based (the output of the backbone is the first block in your figure). "head" refers to everything after the RoI pooling -- in other words what you've labeled as FCN.